# Why after compile c++ code with -O3 flag function generate wrong output?

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-optimization

When in main function i write

```
  Function fun;
  fun.AddName("string1");
  std::cout << fun.GetNumberOfIndeks();
```

**I see on screen two different numbers:**

- 1 (error) when g++ have -O3 flag
- 0 when  g++ have -O0 flag

Below definition of class and methods:

```
class IFunction
{
   public:
     virtual void AddName(std::string nazwa_funkcji) = 0;
     virtual std::size_t GetNumberOfIndeks() = 0;
};

class Function: public IFunction 
{
    public:
       Function();
      void AddName(std::string nazwa_funkcji);
       std::size_t   GetNumberOfIndeks();

    private:
       std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::string>> vp_nazwy_indeksow_;
       std::unique_ptr<::std::string> p_nazwa_;
}

Function::Function():p_nazwa_(new std::string(""))
{

}

std::size_t Function::GetNumberOfIndeks()
{
    vp_nazwy_indeksow_.size();
}

void Function::AddName(std::string nazwa_funkcji)
{
    std::unique_ptr<::std::string> pl_nazwa_funkcji (new std::string(nazwa_funkcji));
    p_nazwa_ = std::move(pl_nazwa_funkcji);
}
```

When i comment second line

```
Function fun;
//fun.AddName("string1");
std::cout << egzFunkcji3.GetNumberOfIndeks();
```

I see on screen expected **zero** with g++ flag -O3.
**Where is the problem ?**

Comment: How do you expect us to answer this if you don't show us half of the code and the code which you show us contains basic syntax errors like a missing semicolon?

Comment: I dont show all code for clarity .. i cut also some methods from class Function. Sorry form mistakes.

Comment: Clarity is good. But you've cut too much.

Comment: I think code is correct. When in CmakeLists.txt i change line

Comment: set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 -pthread") 
to
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O3 -std=c++11 -pthread") 
this problem appears.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Scratch that. First things first. Add "-Wall -Werror" to your compiler flags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your function:

```
std::size_t Function::GetNumberOfIndeks() {
    vp_nazwy_indeksow_.size();
}
```

I count zero return statements which will result in undefined behavior.

**If your compiler didn't warn or error about this, your compiler is trash and should be replaced with a better one.**

Comment: Thanks !!!.
 
I tried to compile above simple code with command

>g++-4.9 -std=c++11 Function.cpp main.cpp

or 

>g++-4.8 -std=c++11 Function.cpp main.cpp

and compiler dont tell me anything about a lack of return statement.

Strange things.

Comment: I strongly recommend using `-Wall -Werror`. gcc 4.8 will provide the error with thos flags. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b44400014438a4a6